# replace button with html area

Tags: php, html

Newbie Alert !

I know I am missing something fundamental but I cannot work out what ...
I have a page with html buttons in a form. The form method is "post" and each button is used to run one of a number of scripts which live on the host webserver and are called (if that is the word) by php ie included on the web page is php script like this:

```
<?php

$cmd = $_POST["action"];
if ($cmd=="snap")
{
    exec("sudo ./snap_web.sh");
}
?>
```

It works just fine but as an exercise, I wanted to substitute a single image for the array of buttons and have user clicks on specific parts of the image take the place of the separate html buttons.
I know how to identify the parts of the image with "coords" but I cannot work out how to pass a click on those areas on to the PHP script in the way that the html button does.
As I "just" want to substitute one html element for another, I am hoping that the answer is simple, but if I have to get into js or other things, so be it !
Many Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please you need to post here your html so we can see what can be doen.

Comment: One thing to note is that you do not directly send something to the PHP Skript. If you submit a form you are sending in most cases a GET or POST Request at a specific file which is in the Webserver. In generel this is a PHP File which processes your request. So you would have to send a Request to the server. Can you show us more of your Code?

Comment: You would have to pass the variables on the querystring if you are using an image map, which means instead of checking for $_POST, you would check for $_GET - [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  If you are going to be submitting other variables when you submit the form, then you cannot use an image map without using js to submit the form

Comment: If your webserver can `sudo`, that's a horrifyingly bad security hole. Additionally, I don't believe `exec()` can sudo at all, even if the account has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with jQuery `$.post()`

The PHP code would be placed into a file on its own. (process.php) for example.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <img src="someImage.png" onclick="calcCoords()">
</form>


<script>
function calcCoords(){
    /**
     *     Here you get the action via to coords however you are currently doing it.
     */
    var action = 'someAction';
    $.post( "process.php", { action: action } function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
}
</script>
```

However, if you wanted the form to submit, without ajax, maybe use javascript to force a $_GET submit?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <img src="someImage.png" onclick="calcCoords()">
</form>


<script>
function calcCoords(){
    /**
     *     Here you get the action via to coords however you are currently doing it.
     */
    var action = 'someAction';
    window.location = window.location + '?action=' + action;
}
</script>
```

Just change your PHP slightly

```
<?php
$cmd = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : null;
if ($cmd=="snap")
{
    exec("sudo ./snap_web.sh");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone who responded. I am clearly in way over my head and need to go back and get some fundamentals straight in my head before continuing with this. I will do that as well as trying the ideas already offered here.

Comment: Oh and whilst I accept the horrible security hole in allowing the webserver to use sudo - I can confirm that it does work on my set up at the moment. But I will change that so that sudo is not needed.